# ios nsnotificationcenter program abort

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

I have gone down quite a few paths and wondered if someone could spot this right off:

I want to display a button when a text field is selected (hence the keyboard is loaded).

From what i've read NSNotificationCenter is one way to do this:

So in viewWillAppear I placed the following

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidAppear:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:self.view.window];
```

for the destination (selector) i have:

```
-(void)keyboardDidAppear{    
  _button2.hidden  = FALSE;
}
```

the program aborts to a crash dump (sure seems like there should be a better debugging path than this)

if I comment out the only line in keyboardDidAppear

```
// _button2.hidden = FALSE;
```

the program still aborts

so evidently the NSNotificationCenter is firing and is not tolerated for some reason

Any simplified help would be appreciated.

Seriously,  the crash dump is all you get when theres an execution error? Is it all you need?

Comment: All you need is a symbolicated stack trace. Oh no, wait, grab a good book on Objective-C first.

Comment: Thanks for the help! RE :Oh wait - I have 3 books on Objective-C - it's very new to me and cryptic though I've been programming for a long time. Once again Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is simple. You register the method `keyboardDidAppear:` but you supply a method named `keyboardDidAppear`. These are not the same (notice the colon).

Change one or the other (but not both).

Another solution would be to implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` and show the button when this is called.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to send a message to `keyboardDidAppear:` but you implemented `keyboardDidAppear`. The first method is a method taking a parameter, but you supplied a method taking no parameters, which of course is different.

Change either your method definition to

```
-(void)keyboardDidAppear:(NSNotification *)n {    
  _button2.hidden = NO; //Please stick to Obj-C semantics and use NO, as opposed to FALSE.
}
```

or the call to

```
@selector(keyboardDidAppear)
```

Comment: ahah thank you Anoop, my way of seeing those is that usually the weirder the error, the more obvious the fix.

Comment: @user2117002 any particular reason why you don't consider this answer accepted anymore?

Comment: I think due to this only SO removed Acceptance percentage, and now it is said you should not ask the user to accept any answer.

Comment: The user already accepted the answer, I was wondering why he changed his mind. Maybe there's something wrong with the answer, but I don't see what.